# Android: How can I search data in sqlite database

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I making project that user can scanning a barcode. My problem is, if the scanning results are the same as the kode_obat column, then the nama_obat, and harga_jual columns will be displayed or setText to Textview.

Please help me, How should I code ?

Here my Code :

MyDatabaseHelper.class

```
private Context context;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Apotek.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private static final String TABLE_NAME = "obat";
private static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
private static final String COLUMN_KODEOBAT = "kode_obat";
private static final String COLUMN_NAMAOBAT = "nama_obat";
//private static final String COLUMN_NOBATCH = "no_batch";
private static final String COLUMN_DISTRIBUTOR = "distributor";
private static final String COLUMN_EXPIRED = "expired_obat";
private static final String COLUMN_SATUAN = "satuan";
private static final String COLUMN_HARGASATUAN = "harga_satuan";
private static final String COLUMN_HARGAJUAL = "harga_jual";
private static final String COLUMN_PRODUSEN = "produsen";
//private static final String COLUMN_STOK = "stok_obat";
//private static final String COLUMN_HARGAOBAT = "harga_obat";


MyDatabaseHelper(@Nullable Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                    " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_KODEOBAT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_NAMAOBAT + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_DISTRIBUTOR + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_EXPIRED + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_SATUAN + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_HARGASATUAN + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_HARGAJUAL + " INTEGER, " +
            COLUMN_PRODUSEN + " TEXT);";
    db.execSQL(query);

    String query1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME1 +
            " (" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " +
            COLUMN_BAYAR + " INTEGER);";
    db.execSQL(query1);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME1);
    onCreate(db);
}

void addObat(String kodeobat, String namaobat, String distributor, String expired, String satuan, int hargasatuan, int hargajual, String produsen){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(COLUMN_KODEOBAT, kodeobat);
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAMAOBAT, namaobat);
    cv.put(COLUMN_DISTRIBUTOR, distributor);
    cv.put(COLUMN_EXPIRED, expired);
    cv.put(COLUMN_SATUAN, satuan);
    cv.put(COLUMN_HARGASATUAN, hargasatuan);
    cv.put(COLUMN_HARGAJUAL, hargajual);
    cv.put(COLUMN_PRODUSEN, produsen);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, cv);
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

void addLaporan(String date, String bayar){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BAYAR, bayar);
    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME1,null, cv);
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Added Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

Cursor readAllData(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    if(db != null){
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
    return cursor;
}

Cursor readAllDataLaporan(){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME1;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = null;
    if(db != null){
        cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    }
    return cursor;
}

void updateObat(String row_id, String kodeobat, String namaobat, String distributor, String expired, String satuan, String hargasatuan, String hargajual, String produsen){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_KODEOBAT, kodeobat);
    cv.put(COLUMN_NAMAOBAT, namaobat);
    cv.put(COLUMN_DISTRIBUTOR, distributor);
    cv.put(COLUMN_EXPIRED, expired);
    cv.put(COLUMN_SATUAN, satuan);
    cv.put(COLUMN_HARGASATUAN, hargasatuan);
    cv.put(COLUMN_HARGAJUAL, hargajual);
    cv.put(COLUMN_PRODUSEN, produsen);

    long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Updated Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

void updateData(String row_id, String date, String bayar){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(COLUMN_DATE, date);
    cv.put(COLUMN_BAYAR, bayar);

    long result = db.update(TABLE_NAME1, cv, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Updated Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}


void deleteOneRow(String row_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

void deleteData(String row_id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    long result = db.delete(TABLE_NAME1, "_id=?", new String[]{row_id});
    if(result == -1){
        Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Delete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Deleted.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

void deleteAllData(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME);
}
```

TransaksiActivity.class

```
EditText ETnamaobattransaksi1, ETnamaobattransaksi2,ETnamaobattransaksi3, ETnamaobattransaksi4, ETnamaobattransaksi5, ETnamaobattransaksi6, ETnamaobattransaksi7,ETnamaobattransaksi8,ETnamaobattransaksi9,ETnamaobattransaksi10,
        EThargaobattransaksi1, EThargaobattransaksi2, EThargaobattransaksi3, EThargaobattransaksi4, EThargaobattransaksi5, EThargaobattransaksi6, EThargaobattransaksi7, EThargaobattransaksi8, EThargaobattransaksi9, EThargaobattransaksi10,
        ETjumlahobattransaksi1, ETjumlahobattransaksi2, ETjumlahobattransaksi3, ETjumlahobattransaksi4, ETjumlahobattransaksi5 , ETjumlahobattransaksi6, ETjumlahobattransaksi7, ETjumlahobattransaksi8, ETjumlahobattransaksi9 ,ETjumlahobattransaksi10, ETcash;

Button BTNScan, BTNcetak, BTNtotal, BTNkembalian;

TextView TVtotalobat1, TVtotalobat2, TVtotalobat3, TVtotalobat4, TVtotalobat5,TVtotalobat6, TVtotalobat7, TVtotalobat8, TVtotalobat9, TVtotalobat10,  TVdate, TVTotalhitungtransaksi, TVTotalhitungtransaksiclick, TVkembalian;

int total1,total2=0,total3=0,total4=0,total5=0,total6=0,total7=0,total8=0,total9=0, total10=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaksi);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    String currentDate = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(calendar.getTime());
    TVdate = findViewById(R.id.TVdate);
    TVdate.setText(currentDate);

 
    ETnamaobattransaksi1 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi1);
    ETnamaobattransaksi2 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi2);
    ETnamaobattransaksi3 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi3);
    ETnamaobattransaksi4 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi4);
    ETnamaobattransaksi5 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi5);
    ETnamaobattransaksi6 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi6);
    ETnamaobattransaksi7 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi7);
    ETnamaobattransaksi8 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi8);
    ETnamaobattransaksi9 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi9);
    ETnamaobattransaksi10 = findViewById(R.id.ETnamaobattransaksi10);

    EThargaobattransaksi1 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi1);
    EThargaobattransaksi2 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi2);
    EThargaobattransaksi3 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi3);
    EThargaobattransaksi4 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi4);
    EThargaobattransaksi5 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi5);
    EThargaobattransaksi6 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi6);
    EThargaobattransaksi7 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi7);
    EThargaobattransaksi8 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi8);
    EThargaobattransaksi9 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi9);
    EThargaobattransaksi10 = findViewById(R.id.EThargaobattransaksi10);

    ETjumlahobattransaksi1 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi1);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi2 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi2);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi3 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi3);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi4 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi4);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi5 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi5);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi6 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi6);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi7 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi7);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi8 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi8);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi9 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi9);
    ETjumlahobattransaksi10 = findViewById(R.id.ETjumlahobattransaksi10);

    TVtotalobat1 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat1);
    TVtotalobat2 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat2);
    TVtotalobat3 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat3);
    TVtotalobat4 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat4);
    TVtotalobat5 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat5);
    TVtotalobat6 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat6);
    TVtotalobat7 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat7);
    TVtotalobat8 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat8);
    TVtotalobat9 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat9);
    TVtotalobat10 = findViewById(R.id.ETtotalobat10);

    BTNtotal = findViewById(R.id.BTNtotal);
    TVTotalhitungtransaksi = findViewById(R.id.TVTotalhitungtransaksi);

    BTNkembalian = findViewById(R.id.BTNkembalian);
    TVkembalian = findViewById(R.id.TVkembalian);

    ETcash = findViewById(R.id.ETcash);

 
    BTNcetak = findViewById(R.id.BTNcetak);
    BTNcetak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MyDatabaseHelper myDB = new MyDatabaseHelper(TransaksiActivity.this);
            myDB.addLaporan(currentDate.toString().trim(),
                    TVTotalhitungtransaksi.getText().toString().trim());
        }
    });

    BTNScan = findViewById(R.id.BTNscan);
    BTNScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            scanCode();
        }
    });


    BTNtotal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String harga1 = EThargaobattransaksi1.getText().toString();
            String jumlah1 = ETjumlahobattransaksi1.getText().toString();
            String harga2 = EThargaobattransaksi2.getText().toString();
            String jumlah2 = ETjumlahobattransaksi2.getText().toString();
            String harga3 = EThargaobattransaksi3.getText().toString();
            String jumlah3 = ETjumlahobattransaksi3.getText().toString();
            String harga4 = EThargaobattransaksi4.getText().toString();
            String jumlah4 = ETjumlahobattransaksi4.getText().toString();
            String harga5 = EThargaobattransaksi5.getText().toString();
            String jumlah5 = ETjumlahobattransaksi5.getText().toString();
            String harga6 = EThargaobattransaksi6.getText().toString();
            String jumlah6 = ETjumlahobattransaksi6.getText().toString();
            String harga7 = EThargaobattransaksi7.getText().toString();
            String jumlah7 = ETjumlahobattransaksi7.getText().toString();
            String harga8 = EThargaobattransaksi8.getText().toString();
            String jumlah8 = ETjumlahobattransaksi8.getText().toString();
            String harga9 = EThargaobattransaksi9.getText().toString();
            String jumlah9 = ETjumlahobattransaksi9.getText().toString();
            String harga10 = EThargaobattransaksi10.getText().toString();
            String jumlah10 = ETjumlahobattransaksi10.getText().toString();

            if(harga1.equals("")&&jumlah1.equals(""))
            {
                int harga1int = 0;
                int jumlah1int = 0;
                total1 = (harga1int*jumlah1int);

            }
            else
            {
                int harga1int = Integer.parseInt(harga1);
                int jumlah1int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah1);
                total1 = (harga1int*jumlah1int);
            }

            if(harga2.equals("")&&jumlah2.equals(""))
            {
                int harga2int = 0;
                int jumlah2int = 0;
                 total2 = (harga2int*jumlah2int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga2int = Integer.parseInt(harga2);
                int jumlah2int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah2);
                 total2 = (Integer.parseInt(harga2)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah2));
            }

            if(harga3.equals("")&&jumlah3.equals(""))
            {
                int harga3int = 0;
                int jumlah3int = 0;
                 total3 = (harga3int*jumlah3int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga3int = Integer.parseInt(harga3);
                int jumlah3int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah3);
                 total3 = (Integer.parseInt(harga3)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah3));
            }

            if(harga4.equals("")&&jumlah4.equals(""))
            {
                int harga4int = 0;
                int jumlah4int = 0;
                 total4 = (harga4int*jumlah4int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga4int = Integer.parseInt(harga4);
                int jumlah4int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah4);
                 total4 = (Integer.parseInt(harga4)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah4));
            }

            if(harga5.equals("")&&jumlah5.equals(""))
            {
                int harga5int = 0;
                int jumlah5int = 0;
                 total5 = (harga5int*jumlah5int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga5int = Integer.parseInt(harga5);
                int jumlah5int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah5);
                 total5 = (Integer.parseInt(harga5)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah5));
            }
            if(harga6.equals("")&&jumlah6.equals(""))
            {
                int harga6int = 0;
                int jumlah6int = 0;
                total6 = (harga6int*jumlah6int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga6int = Integer.parseInt(harga6);
                int jumlah6int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah6);
                total6 = (Integer.parseInt(harga6)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah6));
            }
            if(harga7.equals("")&&jumlah7.equals(""))
            {
                int harga7int = 0;
                int jumlah7int = 0;
                total7 = (harga7int*jumlah7int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga7int = Integer.parseInt(harga7);
                int jumlah7int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah7);
                total7 = (Integer.parseInt(harga7)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah7));
            }
            if(harga8.equals("")&&jumlah8.equals(""))
            {
                int harga8int = 0;
                int jumlah8int = 0;
                total8 = (harga8int*jumlah8int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga8int = Integer.parseInt(harga8);
                int jumlah8int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah8);
                total8 = (Integer.parseInt(harga8)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah8));
            }
            if(harga9.equals("")&&jumlah9.equals(""))
            {
                int harga9int = 0;
                int jumlah9int = 0;
                total9 = (harga9int*jumlah9int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga9int = Integer.parseInt(harga9);
                int jumlah9int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah9);
                total9 = (Integer.parseInt(harga9)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah9));
            }
            if(harga10.equals("")&&jumlah10.equals(""))
            {
                int harga10int = 0;
                int jumlah10int = 0;
                total10 = (harga10int*jumlah10int);
            }
            else
            {
                int harga10int = Integer.parseInt(harga10);
                int jumlah10int = Integer.parseInt(jumlah10);
                total10 = (Integer.parseInt(harga10)*Integer.parseInt(jumlah10));
            }
            int totalbayar = (total1+total2+total3+total4+total5+total6+total7+total8+total9+total10);
            //int totalbayar = (total1);
            TVtotalobat1.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total1));
            TVtotalobat2.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total2));
            TVtotalobat3.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total3));
            TVtotalobat4.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total4));
            TVtotalobat5.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total5));
            TVtotalobat6.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total6));
            TVtotalobat7.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total7));
            TVtotalobat8.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total8));
            TVtotalobat9.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total9));
            TVtotalobat10.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(total10));
            //String texttotalbayar = String.valueOf(totalbayar);
            TVTotalhitungtransaksi.setText("Rp."+String.valueOf(totalbayar));

            BTNkembalian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String bayar = ETcash.getText().toString();
                    int bayarint  = Integer.parseInt(bayar);
                    int kembalian = bayarint - totalbayar;
                    TVkembalian.setText(String.valueOf("Rp."+kembalian));

                }
            });



private void scanCode()
{
    ScanOptions options = new ScanOptions();
    options.setPrompt("Volume to flash on");
    options.setBeepEnabled(true);
    options.setOrientationLocked(true);
    options.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
    barLauncher.launch(options);

}
ActivityResultLauncher<ScanOptions> barLauncher = registerForActivityResult(new ScanContract(), result ->
{
    if(result.getContents() !=null)
    {
        String namaobattransaksi1 = ETnamaobattransaksi1.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi2 = ETnamaobattransaksi2.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi3 = ETnamaobattransaksi3.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi4 = ETnamaobattransaksi4.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi5 = ETnamaobattransaksi5.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi6 = ETnamaobattransaksi6.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi7 = ETnamaobattransaksi7.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi8 = ETnamaobattransaksi8.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi9 = ETnamaobattransaksi9.getText().toString();
        String namaobattransaksi10 = ETnamaobattransaksi10.getText().toString();

        for(int f = 1; f<10; f++){

    }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(TransaksiActivity.this);
        //ETnamaobat.setText(result.getContents());


        if(namaobattransaksi1.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi1.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi2.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi2.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi3.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi3.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi4.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi4.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi5.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi5.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi6.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi6.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi7.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi7.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi8.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi8.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else if (namaobattransaksi9.equals(""))
        {
            ETnamaobattransaksi9.setText(result.getContents());
        }
        else{
            ETnamaobattransaksi10.setText(result.getContents());
        }

        builder.setTitle("Result");
        builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).show();

    }
    result.getContents().equals(null);

});
```

activity_transaksi.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/utama"
    android:stretchColumns="1,2,3"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    tools:context=".TransaksiActivity"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
    </TableRow>


    <TableRow>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ETnamaobattransaksi1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Nama Obat"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ETjumlahobattransaksi1"
            android:layout_width="27dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:hint="Jumlah"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/EThargaobattransaksi1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Harga Obat"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ETtotalobat1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Total Obat"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
    </TableRow>
     
    <TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <!--<TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVTotalhitungtransaksiclick"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:text="Total :   Rp."
            android:gravity="right"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="3"
            />-->
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTNtotal"
            android:layout_width="85sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:backgroundTint="#5a8f7b"
            android:text="total"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVTotalhitungtransaksi"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="4"
            android:hint="Total"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textColorHint="#A2B5BB"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <!--<View
            android:id="@+id/line1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:padding="2dip" />-->
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/BTNscan"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="scan"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:layout_span="4"
            android:layout_column="1"/>

    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think don't invest time for solving this problem try use Room is the best way for local database

Comment: Don't vandalize your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do the search in the database thing you will need to add this code.

```
SQLiteDatabase database = new MyDatabaseHelper(context).getReadableDatabase();
@SuppressLint("Recycle") Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + 
       MyDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAMAOBAT + " , " + MyDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_HARGAJUAL +" FROM " + MyDatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + MyDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_KODEOBAT  + " = '" + YOUR_TEXT_HERE +"'", null);
if(cursor.getCount()>0){
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      YOUR_TEXTVIEW1.setText(cursor.getString(0));  
      YOUR_TEXTVIEW2.setText(cursor.getString(1));
        
}
else{
      DO_YOUR_CODE_HERE

}
```

I hope this will help.

And you didn't have to post all of the code just a small sample,
Actually, in your case, you don't have to post any of this.

Comment: Thanks for the help
This is my first post in stack overflow, idk how to write a post, ma bad broo

Comment: I would probably put it in a separate class and getText from a static method (if it is used a lot) and then call it where I want and setText to the text view,
or if it used once only just add it in your activity calss  in a thread @hans

Comment: the context is your activity context, you can get it by using getApplicationContext(); @hans